# running mulitple commands using Subprocess.Popen in the same shell

Tags: windows, python-2.7, shell, cmd, subprocess

Hi I am at a loss on how to run multiple commands using popen,
I am trying to automate a series of steps that are normally run on the Windows command line. The basic steps are usually run from the Windows cmd line are

1. Run a windows command script (.cmd) file to setup environment variables i.e C:\Program Files (x86)\appsettings\setupvariables.cmd
2. type in the command to connect to the database
3. type in the command to get data from the database
4. Stop connection to the database

All these commands must run in the same command line window one after another, not separate processes or separate command line windows. Instead of opening a cmd window and typing in the command I want to use python's subprocess.popen command

So far I have:

```
args=[]
args.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\appsettings\setmyvars.cmd')
args.append(r'start db on db_path="my_url"')
args.append(r'get_data_from_db>c:\temp\output.txt')
args.append(r'stop db on db_path="my_url"')

p=Popen(args,stdout=PIPE,sterr=PIPE,shell=True)
stdout,stderr=p.communicate()
if stderr:
    print "you have an error", stderr
else:
    print "well done you have data", stdout
```

This isn't quite working I can see that the first line is run i.e the setmyvars.cmd is executed, but nothing else, none of the other arguments get called, if they did I would see the results in the ouput.txt file.

How do I run a series of commands one after the other using popen. Why is it only the first command seems to be executed and none of the others

I am using python2.7 on Windows

Regards.

Comment: You can concatenate commands using `&`, but why not create a single batch file for this?

Comment: Also, use a string instead of an args list with `shell=True`. Generally subprocess doesn't know how to build a command line for cmd.exe with escaping of special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues going on. You still have to tell popen() which program to run. Just using `shell=True` does not obviate the need to provide `cmd.exe` as the program to run. If you really want to run all of these commands with one invocation of cmd.exe, then you will need to string them together with `&&`.

```
from subprocess import *

args=[]
args.append(r'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe')
args.append(r'/C')
args.append(r'(echo 1 && echo 2 && echo 4)')

p = Popen(args,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,shell=True)
stdout,stderr=p.communicate()
if stderr:
    print "you have an error", stderr
else:
    print "well done you have data", stdout
```

It would probably be better to use the %ComSpec% environment variable than it would be to hardcode the location of cmd.exe. The path you have is -usually- correct. :-)